# windows command line: how to remove space in file

Tags: windows, command-line

In linux, we can do it with tr command to remove space. 
How can I do it in windows?
I like to remove space in each line of a text file from command line in Windows XP.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a windows shell script example from http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.RemoveSpaces

```
set str=      word       &rem
echo."%str%"
set str=%str: =%
echo."%str%"
```

Comment: Have fun doing so with an actual file. If you want a challenge, throw in random `>`, `<`, `&`, `|` and unmatched quotes into it. While removing spaces *is* trivial, proper handling or arbitrary input isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a scripting language (Powershell, Python, Perl...) or use tr via Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use "SET filter=%*" to remove leading and trailing spaces?

```
@ECHO Off

SET source=  1 2 3 4 5  
ECHO Source string = "%source%"
CALL :SpaceCut %source%
ECHO Beginning and ending spaces removed = "%filter%"

pause
exit /b

:SpaceCut
SET filter=%*
exit /b
```